# Postgres 10 - Targeting schema's function on a multiple schema Database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm running **PostgresSQL 10**, and I have several schemas on my DB with multiple functions. I've created a schemaless script with all the functions on it (I've removed the schema prefix), with this, everytime i create a new schema, I ran the migration and create all the functions as well.
This was necessary/requested for a better data separation between customers. All the schemas are twins in terms of structure.

All was fine until I figured that SchemaA was calling a function from public. Even if I call:

`SchemaA.myFunction(p_param1:= 'A', p_param2:= 'B')`.

If this "myFunction" calls another from the inside, it will target `public` schema by default.

The only way I made it work, was using an input parameter called **p_user_schema** `myFunction(p_param1, p_param2, p_user_schema)` and add the following statement as the first line of **myFunction** body.

`EXECUTE FORMAT('SET search_path TO %L', p_user_schema);`

I've 147 functions, I will need to adapt each of these, does anyone know a better way to target the callers schema, by callers I mean the prefix schema used on the main call.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the search path at the function level with the current user as the 1st one

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemaA.myfunction()
RETURNS ..
AS  $$
 ...
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
SET SEARCH_PATH = "$user", public;
```

Comment: I've added a line `RAISE NOTICE 'schema: %', current_schema;` it prints: **schema: public**, seems it's not working :(.

Comment: That should work if the username is "schemaA". Else maybe you could set the search_path at the user level. But in both case, make sure to test using an end-user, not you the admin

Comment: I see, the problem is this is a cloud based, the user used to log, is a service user created by the provider, not me, I can't create users. Maybe this is a limitation.